# Update of security update hangs for Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: mojave, software-update

I have a Mac mini (late 2014). I did install an SSD disk to increase its performance.

Current Mac Mojave version: 10.14.6
Update: Security update 2020-003 10.14.6

I did this:

1. Boot my mac using Verbose mode by pressing CMD + V after the booting chime
2. Choose install update in the update dialog

Please note that I had installed a new SSD drive which might be related to this problem.

What I tried so far:

- Unplug all USB devices except the native apple Keyboard
- Activate safemode and verbose mode which gave me an error:

  ```
    sudo nvram boot-args="-v -x"
  ```

When installing the update and booting in verbose mode I keep seeing the following line around 30 times:

```
Failed to send exception EXC_COPRPSE_NOTIFY. error code: 5 for pid 94
...
X68PlatformPlugin result 0
```

[Etrecheck Report](https://pastebin.com/LFJwANLQ)

Interestingly the Etrecheck report tells me that the update was installed:

> Software Installs (past 30 days):
>
> ```
> Install Date Name (Version)  
> ....
> 2020-07-06 Sicherheitsupdate 2020-003 (10.14.6)
> ```

But the Update keeps showing up:

[image: Softwareupdate]

Answer (score 1):

I did figure out the culprit was a piece of software that was loaded using `LaunchDaemons` that somehow prevented a clean shutdown or startup. After backing up and deleting the LaunchDaemon files the update could be installed without any problems.

I could find more infos on the website: https://helpcenter.graphisoft.com/knowledgebase/75010/